# Intel xdk Cordova Build BETA

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

So i got that message when i try to build with cordova:

Cordova Build BETA
BUILD THE CORDOVA APPLICATION
You can now build your Cordova application. All options, with the exception of certificates, are pulled from the config.xml configuration file you included at the root of your application in the Intel XDK.

For configuration options for your application, take a look at the Cordova Apache project or the Intel intelxdk.config.xml configuration documentation.

What should i do? Please step by step!

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for Cordova build using [**Intel XDK**](http://xdk.intel.com), there is also link for sample `intelxdk.config.xml` file:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/using-the-cordova-for-android-ios-etc-build-option

- Build your app and test in XDK
- add the `intelxdk.config.xml` to the app and build for Cordova